# How to dynamically re-evaluate a function with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've setup the following jQuery function to add a negative left margin to a `<div>` element

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var docwidth = $(document).width();
    var herowidth = $('.element-hero').width();
    var leftmargin = docwidth - herowidth;

    $('.element-hero').css({ "margin-left": -leftmargin,});

});
```

As you can see, it gets the document width, the `<div class="element-hero">` width, and applies to the latter a negative left margin equal to the difference between these two values.

It works fine, until I try to resize the browser window; I need the value of the left margin to be dynamically re-calculated when the window is resized (without reloading, of course).

Right now, if we assume, in example, initial values of `docwidth = 1200px` and `herowidth = 900px`, the left margin is set to `-300px`; If I resize the window to have `docwidth = 1400px`, I expect to have a margin of `-500px`, but this is not what really happens, the original calculated value of `-300px` is kept until I manually reload the window.

From what I get, the problem is that using `.ready()` runs the script once after the document is fully loaded; I also need this value to be calculated everytime that the window is resized, and be updated accordingly.

How should I modify this code?

Comment: Just review the jQuery event list, https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: You could use `$( window ).resize(function() {//Anything goes in here});`. For further documentation you might would like to take a look at: https://api.jquery.com/resize/
Also do not forget to use braces when assigning substraction and adding formula's to variables: `var leftmargin = (docwidth - herowidth);`

Comment: @Barrosy do you mean that there is something wrong with `var leftmargin = docwidth - herowidth;`?

Comment: @JamesT No but it is good practice to do that.

Comment: @JamesT It is good practice because you will never know in what kind of context your variable will end up in and operators in programming language follow a certain priority when executing. This would be a different discussion so I will leave it as this.

Comment: @Barrosy Thank you, I've managed to modify it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with the following code:

```
var heroMargin = function(){

    var docwidth = $(document).width();
    var herowidth = $('.element-hero').width();
    var leftmargin = (docwidth - herowidth);

    $('.element-hero').css({ "margin-left": -leftmargin,});

};

$(document).ready(heroMargin);

$(window).resize(heroMargin);
```

Comment: It's actually nicer to use a function rather than the way I did it in my answer (repetetive code). Will update my answer when available.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from your code is that you are trying to reset the spacing between the document and the element `<div class="element-hero"></div>` . Using JQuery for this might not be the best approach and it would be wiser to just use some kind of CSS reset sheet or framework like Bootstrap to achieve this (reason being it is easier to achieve the same without JavaScript trying to mess up your document).

Closest I got was something along the lines of this:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egz1wxs8/)

```js
let resetMargin = function resetMarginFunc() {
  let docwidth = $(document).width();
  let herowidth = $('.element-hero').width();
  let margins = ((docwidth - herowidth) / 2);
  $('.element-hero').css({
      "margin-left": -(margins)
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //On init:
  resetMargin();
  
  //On resize:  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    //Set new values of the elements after a resize:
    resetMargin();
  });
});
```

```css
/*In order to make element visible and view changes:*/
.element-hero {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element-hero">  
</div>
```

Make sure to resize your browser window when viewing the result here on SO or resize the document window on the JSFiddle page in order to view the result.

Please let me know if you have any more questions (leave them in the comments below).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I was trying to do was not to do a CSS reset. I was trying to play around a layout where *just a part* of a column had to go under another transparent column.

Comment: Please provide me with examples so that I can change my answer so that it revolves more around your specifics. @Sekhemty

Comment: I don't understand, what kind of examples?

Comment: You are talking about "just a part of a column" and "go under another transparent column". Please show me the available code you have for this (e.g. HTML, CSS and JavaScript). @Sekhemty

Comment: It is a full Wordpress page template, made with Bootstrap; it is not very practical to share all the code, and I have already solved this problem.